# Render looks worse than viewport, and the animated version looks even worse

Tags: rendering, animation, color, resolution

New to Blender and 3d animation here, so I'm probably missing something important with this.
So, my project looks good in my viewport, can't really see any pixels.[image: Viewport Screenshot]

When I render it as an image you can see a lot of pixels when you zoom in, I think that might be normal though.[image: Zoomed In Rendered Image]
But the funky part is that when I render the animation it looks way worse.[image][image]
Colors get separated into large blocks, and the quality drops. It's way more noticeable when there are black colors.
Is there a way I can make it look like the viewport?

Comment: You provide no information about how your scene is set up, how your render is set up, which render engine you are using, how the elements in your scene are created, which formats you are rendering your images/animation... how are we supposed to give an answer more than wild guessing? Please provide more details or even better upload your file with packed images here: https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there to edit it into your question.